# How to reduce time taken by iframe to render page?

Tags: asp.net

I designed a html page, which contains 4 Iframes.

When I run the project html contents rendered early and iframe takes time to render the content.

My question is how to make the Iframe responsive enough to render the content?

(Or)

Is there any alternative for iframe, which I can use to call dynamic pages on html page?

(Or)

Should i make one aspx page instead of making one html page and Iframes?

Which is better????

this is my code
Example.html

```
<body>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
<div id="wrapper" class="homepage-1"> 


<iframe id="ff" width="100%" height="350px" frameborder="0" src="Test.aspx"></iframe>

</div>
</body>
</html>


Test.aspx looks like this
 <div class="home-testimonial clearfix">
    <div class="container">

            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="slogan-section animated  clearfix">
                    <h2><span>Testimonial</span></h2>
                      </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center" >
                <div class="flexslider-three animated ">
                      <ul class="slides">
                         <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" EnableTheming="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                 <li>
                             <blockquote>
                                <br /><br />
                                 <h4><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></h4>
                            </blockquote>
                             <div class="testimonial-footer clearfix">

                                <div class="for-border"></div>
                                 <p class="font-title"> <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Review") %>' Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label></p>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Test.aspx.cs looks like this
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;


public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Dll dobj = new Dll();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Bind();


        }
    }
    private void Bind()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = dobj.Alldata("Viewtestimonial");
        Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Comment: It very much depends on the project. Many times you can avoid iframes, but sometimes there is no way around. It would be much more helpful if you could provide more details on your project and post some code that causes content-rendering delays.

Comment: Then is it better to make one aspx page???

Comment: It's best to deal with questions one at a time. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which causes the delays in rendering and some more details about your project.

Comment: i posted some code.please give answer.

Comment: Thanks in advance for help